# jsonschema Draft7 multiple custom types in python

Tags: python, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I am trying to add several custom types to my validators

at the moment i have one that verifies date types. I want to add another to verify positive integers

```
from datetime import date

date_checker = Draft7Validator.TYPE_CHECKER.redefine("date", lambda _, instance: isinstance(instance, date))
custom_validator = validators.extend(Draft7Validator, type_checker=date_checker)
validator = custom_validator(schema={"type": "date"})
validator.validate(config, schema)
```

How can I add another different type to the same validator object?

Answer (score 3):

After playing with a few variations I got this working. I am not 100% sure if this is the best way to do it....but it works

```
date_checker = Draft7Validator.TYPE_CHECKER.redefine_many({
    "date": lambda _, instance: isinstance(instance, date),
    "pos_int": lambda _, instance: isinstance(instance, int) and instance >= 0
})

custom_validator = validators.extend(Draft7Validator, type_checker=date_checker)
validator = custom_validator(schema)
validator.validate(config)
```

Comment: I'm trying to recreate your solution, but instantiating custom validator with schema `{'type': 'date'}` gives a `SchemaError` on `schema['type'] = 'date'` which makes sense as there is no "date" type defined in the meta schema